# not getting value in $_post array

Tags: php

this is my form code, when i am submitting the form i am not getting data in post array,i tried multiple methods but not receiving any response after clicking the button, here is the code

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo print_r($_POST);
    }
?> 

// other stuff

<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post" action="#" >


  <span class="section">Info</span>

  <div class="item form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Name <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <input id="name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" data-validate-length-range="6" data-validate-words="2" name="name" placeholder="both name(s) e.g Jon Doe" required="required" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="textarea">Description <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <textarea id="description" required="required" name="description" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="textarea">Type <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <select id="type" name="type" required="required" class="selectpicker form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
        <option title="Combo 1">Weekly</option>
        <option title="Combo 2">Monthly</option>
        <option title="Combo 3">Annually</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ln_solid"></div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <button  type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: when you submit this, can you view your HTML source and tell us what you see; is it "code"? Because that should work.

Comment: I think your form action needs to have the destination of the POST request.

Comment: In addition to my first comment, add an `else { echo "No joy" ;}` does it go there? does it "echo" anything?

Comment: its the same @Fred-ii-

Comment: that doesn't answer my question, the "first" question. Define "same".

Comment: Or an `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Are you running this from a web server or just opening the file locally from your browser?

Comment: @Blkc It does have a destination...

Comment: what's the file extension for this? are you running off a webserver? hosted? local? how? `http://localhost/` or `file:///`? too many questions to be asked

Comment: @Nick sorry didn't realize it is on the same file. Can try using form.submit via jquery.

Comment: @Blkc jQuery? What? Why??

Comment: its on local server, and i yes i can view the same html code after submitting form and i also tried else condition it print the else part when i load the page and after submitting it prints the same like else condition

Comment: @j08691 sorry I was retarded. just document.getElementById(<id>).submit();

Comment: @AsifMehmood `action="#"` won't submit the form to the server. If you want it to submit to the same URL that displayed the form, use `action=""`.

Comment: @Barmar still not submitting :(

Comment: This code is perfectly work on my localhost without any edit [print.scr](https://prnt.sc/fk69h9)

Comment: @NebojsaNebojsa i am shocked why its not working here, i know code is okay.

Comment: @AsifMehmood did you tried to change to `$_GET` just to test

Comment: if (isset($_GET)) {
                      echo print_r($_GET);
                    }else { echo "No joy" ;}

Comment: i am using above right now

Comment: and refreshing page it is printing array

Comment: empty array and on submitting button it shows nothig

Comment: @NebojsaNebojsa i added this script at the end of page when i remove it then form works otherwise not
<script src="../vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

change form action. and change button type

> Block quote

`<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />`

Comment: yes, i think you forgot to add name to the form. add some name to form and try again thanks

Comment: <script src="../vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
this script is not letting me to submit the form dont know why

Comment: Why did you post two different answers?

Answer (score 0):

Try it now :

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            echo print_r($_POST);
        }
    ?> 

    // other stuff

    <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
      <span class="section">Info</span>

      <div class="item form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Name <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <input id="name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" data-validate-length-range="6" data-validate-words="2" name="name" placeholder="both name(s) e.g Jon Doe" required="required" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="textarea">Description <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <textarea id="description" required="required" name="description" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="textarea">Type <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <select id="type" name="type" required="required" class="selectpicker form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
            <option title="Combo 1">Weekly</option>
            <option title="Combo 2">Monthly</option>
            <option title="Combo 3">Annually</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ln_solid"></div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <button  type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: nothing i just added else part and it is showing me the else part :(

Comment: change all $_POST to $_REQUEST and try once again

Comment: may i kno what php version are u running ?

Comment: 7.1.1 version of php

Comment: <script src="../vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
this script is not letting me to submit the form dont know whyyyy

Comment: @AsifMehmood There's no Javascript in the question, so that shouldn't be relevant. Is there code you haven't shown us that's handling the `submit` event?

Comment: there isn't any code which handling submit, but i am doing validation through jquerymin.js that's it

Comment: where is the code for validation, u should have mentioned it earlier... !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines in your code

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post" action="#" >
<button  type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

With

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input  type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

there was script in my code

```
<script src="../vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and i name my button "submit" so the error was in console

```
submit is not a function
```

so when i change the name of my button to "btnsubmit" it works fine.
When you name the button submit, you override the submit() function on the form.